# Using TransactionScope with typed dataset

Tags: .net, winforms, transactions, transactionscope, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a WinForm application querying SqlCe database using typed-dataset tabledapters. I have a main form assembly and a database assembly which handles every db operation. I'm having problems with updating using tableadapter in a transaction and I'd appreciate if anyone could give me any ideas why.

Update() method gives this error:

```
"The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope."
```

Here's my code:

```
namespace Main
{
    public class MainForm
    {
        private MyDbAssembly.MyDbClass db;

        //instantiate and db fill methods omitted..

        private void DeleteStuff()
        {
            using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
            {
                this.db.Delete(id);
                UpdateDb();

                trans.Complete();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDb()
        {
            //bindingsource endedit & datagridview endedit methods omitted..
            this.db.Update();
        }
    }
}

namespace MyDbAssembly
{
    public class MyDbClass
    {
        private myTypedDataset myDataSet;
        private myTypedDataSetTableAdapter.MyTable1Adapter table1Adapter;

        //instantiate methods omitted..

        public void Delete(Guid id)
        {
            this.myDataSet.MyTable1.FindByID(id).Delete();  
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            this.table1Adapter.Update(myDataSet.MyTable); //<-- ERROR LINE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602421

Comment: No it's not the same. That question was if it would work, this one is about the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 1):

Because you created the table1Adapter outside the TransactionScope trans scope.